# Flutter authenticated WebSocket communication with SignalR backend

Tags: flutter, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working on a mobile application using flutter and dart. I need to establish websocket connection with backend which is implemented using Asp.net SiganlR. Backend is implemented by other team and I cannot modify/update it. The websocket communication is protected at the backend and I need to provide access token in order to access the service.

I am trying this code to establish a communication channel:

```
IOWebSocketChannel _channel = new IOWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://localhost:5000/sinkhub', headers: {
        'X-TOKEN': 'token'
       });
```

But I am not able to establish the connection and end up having error. This is the screenshot of the _channel object after executing above code.

[image]

Any help in this regard is appreciated. More specifically, how to connect to signalR backend from flutter app. Most important point to note is, backend is protected and I need to send access token in order to access the service.

Comment: ,did you get the solution

Answer (score 1):

I am using package [signalr_client 0.1.6](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_client)

Lets say you are storing token in local storage. So create a method to retrieve it like below.

```
  Future<String> getAccessToken() async {
    FlutterSecureStorage _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    return await _storage.read(key: 'token');
  }
```

Now you need to use this method when you are building your hub connection.

```
  Future startConnection() async {
    connection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://************/hubs/chatHub',
            options: HttpConnectionOptions(
                accessTokenFactory: () async =>
                    await getAccessToken()))
        .build();
    await connection.start();
  }
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!